# Using IQueryable with repository pattern in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, ddd-repositories

I need an advice on DDD (Domain Driven Design) and implementation of Repository pattern and encapsulation.
To my understanding is that Repository pattern enables me to put all the database access logic in one place and abstract that logic from other parts of application.
On the other side there is orm (Nhibernate, EntityFramework...) with its support for Linq and IQueryable.
My toughts are: 
1. If I am using repository then I should not use IQueryable as my return type bust instead use IEnumerable. Because if I use IQueryable then this would allow leaking database code to other application layers (IE would allow other devs to do queries in mvc controller where they don't belong).
But every controls use IQueryable to access data and does this because is easier.
If I use IQueryable as return type of my repository methods then:
- I allow other developers to do database querying in other layers of application (and I think this should not be possible)
- It will leak my domain entities (domain model) to other layers of applications (ie. User interface) but should not, instead DTO should be used.

My question is is IQueryable a good practice in DDD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say it's not a good practice. 
Ideally you should have some sort of application layer on top of your domain. If you expose your domain objects directly or through Query object, someone might actually modify it outside of your control.

Personally i like to think of IQueryable as an implementation detail, ideally my domain would not depend on it (in case i want to switch my storage technology it could be a problem). 
Most often i'll end up using IQueryable internally inside my repositories implementation. What i usually end up with is implementing generic repository that has a FindBySpecification method, and then have specialized repositories for every Aggregate root that inherits from it. For example:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity>        
{
    TEntity Get(Guid ID);
    void Add(TEntity entity);
    void Remove(TEntity entity);
    void Detach(TEntity entity);
    IEnumerable<TEntity> WithSpecification(ISpecification<TEntity> specification);
}

public interface IOrdersRepository : IRepository<Order>
{
    IEnumerable<Order> GetCompletedOrdersForAllPreferedCustomers(DateTime orderCompletedAfter);
    Order GetOrderBySomeOtherComplicatedMeans();
}
```

Another aproach is to design your application to follow the CQRS principle. 
Then you can have your DomainModel doing it's magic on the command side, and create a readonly model of your data for your client on the query side. 
This setup can become really elaborate depending on your requirements, but it can be as simple as two ORM models mapped to the same database (the one on the command side is mapping your domain entities, the one on the query sides maps to simple DTOs ).

Comment: The problem I have is that we use DevExpress controls on MVC application. And GridView pagination is siply when you're using IQueriable. But if you use another data mechanism it becomes quite tedious to implement Custom data binding on all the grids.

Comment: And Yes, I am using some sort of CQRS (without event sourcing), but have only one orm model. On the write side I use commands that can change behavior, on the read side I use the same orm model but exposed as DTO objects

Comment: No, no inplace editing. But still I need some way of Pagination and Ordering. Filtering is another question because read side does not directly access entities, but only DTO objects. The way I'm doing it now is to pass page index and count to the method in repository where I do pagination. I'm aware that using IQueriable in application layer would be much easier to do  with Skip().Take().

Comment: Well the best way to go i guess is to have your orm map your tables to simple POCO classes and then use factories to create your domain entities on the write side, this way you can use the same ORM for the read side, this would involve more code,but would be more generic solution i guess. It all depends on your project, for a smaller project with a realativly stable DB schema i would create a separate ORM mapping just for the read side. It's a tradeoff either way.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I do not feel that exposing EF entities by way of IQueryable across all layers is necessarily a bad thing. But this is just my own opinion. Others may not agree especially if you look at it on the encapsulation perspective. But generally the concept of loose-coupling is a trade-off between complexity and practical gain. By encapsulating IQueryable know that you will loose a lot of practical gain, like the ability to lazy-load for instance.

If your application layer is directly on top of your repository layer, I vote to use IEnnumerable instead of IQueryable. But if you have a service layer in the middle (which I personally prefer to contain all business logic so the repository layer can specialize with data access operations) then I will have the repository return IQueryable and have the service layer return IEnnumerable after it has performed its business logic from the IQueryable object returned by the repository.

These are just my own personal rules:

1. If you need to encapsulate EF, encapsulate it away only from the application layer. Otherwise, use it as excessively as you need on all layers. EF is very powerful, encapsulating it in the repository layer will make you lose a lot of its power
2. The application layer should be as thin as possible, it should not perform any further processing on the data it receives from the layer below it. It receives the list and it renders it, that's it.

Comment: Yes I have Application layer above the Dal layer. My Central layer is the DomainModel. And my Application layer is a thin facade to the domain layer that is there only as a plumbing layer that coordinates other layers. Domain Business logic is keept in domain layer.

Comment: The need for lazy loading means your aggregates are not properly designed.